# d3 data selection for creating a simple chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the following data structure to create a chart in D3.js:

```
var tasklist = {
  "tasks": {
    "task1": {
      "TASKSTARTTIME": "2018-09-07T07:36:19.990Z",
    },
    "task2": {
      "TASKSTARTTIME": "2018-09-07T07:36:20.010Z",
    },
    "task3": {
      "TASKSTARTTIME": "2018-09-07T07:36:20.100Z",
    }
  }
}
```

and have successfully set the x & y domains of my chart like so:

```
x.domain(d3.extent(Object.entries(tasklist.tasks).map(([d, v]) => (v["TASKSTARTTIME"]))));
y.domain(Object.entries(tasklist.tasks).map(([d, v]) => (d)));
```

but I think this must be wrong as when I look at other examples the syntax appears much cleaner.

So, my first question is: Is there a more correct D3 way to achieve the same result?

Question 2: How would I select the individual data points to be plotted?  I tried the follow for the x axis:

```
([d,v]) => (x(v["TASKSTARTTIME"]))
```

and

```
d => y(d)
```

but it didn't work.  I haven't included the whole code, because (I think) these can be tested from the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you've seen elsewhere is cleaner because most people store D3.js data in Arrays, rather than Objects. You could try changing your data to Array format -- it simplifies the code quite a bit:

```js
var tasks = [
  {name: 'task1', 'time': '2018-09-07T07:36:19.990Z'},
  {name: 'task2', 'time': '2018-09-07T07:36:20.010Z'}
]

var xDomain = d3.extent(tasks, d => d.time)
var yDomain = d3.extent(tasks, d => d.name)

console.log({x: xDomain, y: yDomain});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```